# Laravel 5.5 administrator route issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have the below mentioned route:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('administrator', array('before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'Administrator\IndexController@index'));
//Route::get('/administrator', 'Administrator\IndexController@index');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'administrator'], function() {

Route::get('login', 'Administrator\IndexController@index')->name('login');
 Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@doLogin'); 
 Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

My intention is when someone try to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/administrator/ this will go directly to the login page of the administrator.

However, when I tried to access the same, it said 404 not found.

IndexController under Administrator folder is looks below:

```
class IndexController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('doLogout');
    }

    public function index() {
        //$session = session()->all();
        if(Auth::check() == 1){
            return Redirect::intended('/administrator/dashboard')->with('successMessage', 'You have successfully logged in.');
        }
        //print_r($session);
        //echo $session['_token'];
        //if($session['_token'] == '')
        $data = array();
        $data['title'] = "Shop To My Door - Administrator Panel";
        return view('Administrator.index.index', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do your other routes work? Do you have a folder in `public` called `administrator` perhaps?

Comment: can you show your indexcontroller?

Comment: @AliÖzen - question updated.

Comment: @ceejayoz - yes, if I write 'admin' in route, it work.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks. Now I got it.

Comment: @ceejayoz - So, do I rename the Administrator folder under Public directory? Or place an htaccess file with deny all ? need your suggestion..

Comment: If you can rename either the folder or the route, that should do the trick.

Comment: @ceejayoz renaming the folder or route are not possible right now. Can you provide me the htaccess content which will not read the Administrator directory under public and get me the result as I wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have route and group with the same name "administrator"

My suggestion for routing:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'administrator'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'Administrator\IndexController@index');
    Route::get('login', 'Administrator\IndexController@login');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@doLogin'); 
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

Comment: So is it not feasible?

Comment: My intention is when someone try to access administrator/ it will show the login under administrator.

Comment: Try to remove administrator route and move index action under administrator group. That should do the trick.

Comment: Can you kindly post this as answer with example?